# Unable to get website reroute location in Insomnia

Tags: web-scraping, https, http-post, insomnia

I am developing a school mobile app that has no access to the school API and so I have tried to scrape data from the school website, [CLiC](https://clic.mmu.edu.my/psp/csprd/?cmd=login). After pressing the Sign In button, in the response headers there should be a location pointing to the error login page. When I posted some data to the form action url in Insomnia, I couldn't find any headers related to the reroute location.

Here's the data that I posted

```
{
    "lcsrf_token": "1CrcNP9TrLqho8WS+UGA2Tjg5JKV1zjdM3K+quZJKUY=",
    "timezoneOffset": -480,
    "ptmode": "f",
    "ptlangcd": "ENG",
    "ptinstalledlang": "ENG",
    "userid": "",
    "pwd": ""
}
```

All of the data except for the `userid` and `pwd` can be found in the website's html as hidden item.

I have also tested posting with cookies that have exactly same structure as shown in the browser, but the outcome remains the same.

Could someone enlighten me on where did I do wrongly?

Comment: try to use the same exact header

Comment: it turns out I was using the wrong content-type and user-agent in my request headers, now that switching the content-type to form-url-encoded and with the exact user-agent as a browser, the reroute location appears in the response headers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is due to **wrong body format** specified in `Content-Type: form-url-encoded` header and that's causing the issue.

Changing the body to the specified type resolved the issue.